# 920 HTTP response

Tags: python, http, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have a script written in Python that runs perfectly on my local machine. When I deploy it on Jenkins (which is running on an Amazon machine) and run it from there I get 920 HTTP response.

Any idea about why is this happening?

Comment: Does the script work if you run if manually from the Jenkins machine? What is the content of the script? What is the HTTP request being sent? What is the web server you're hitting? There are too few details here.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mistype 920, for 420? According to the HTTP status codes, 920 doesn't exist.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error

Comment: It is 920. I'm using `requests` library and the code returned is 920. Apparently, it exists somehow: https://webcron.org/fr/http-codes

Comment: Jenkins is not written using Spring.